# Why are thin-film surface-mount resistors particularly suitable for use in cryogenic environments/conditions?

Tags: resistors, temperature, surface-mount, optoelectronics

I am currently studying *The Art of Electronics*, third edition, by Horowitz and Hill. Appendix **C.4 Resistor types** says the following:

> The usual choices for general-purpose use are metal-film  (axial-lead) or thick-film (surface-mount) parts. Thin-film  surface-mount resistors offer improved characteristics (accuracy, stability, and ability to operate in cryogenic environments).

Why are thin-film surface-mount resistors particularly suitable for use in cryogenic environments/conditions? I know that there are some optoelectronic devices that require cryogenic conditions to operate, so I'm curious about this.

Comment: I guess you should google the material they're made of. There are temperature classes for devices. Wikipedia should have some info about it. For example, caps have things like X5R, X7R etc. I'm no expert in that, but it's clearly about the material, so you should be able to find something

Comment: @Ilya I'm a novice, so it's not exactly clear to me what I should be looking at/for.

Comment: I don't really know anything about material, never cared for my applications, but quick google search of "thin film resistors material" gave me this: https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/thin-film-resistors#:~:text=Thin%2Dfilm%20resistor%20materials%20are,provides%20a%20far%20greater%20range.
 and it looks good. It discusses thermal drift of resistos. You can google that material further if you like

Comment: @Ilya Ahh, that was indeed helpful. It seems that thin-film chip resistors are particularly suitable because they have a low "temperature coefficient of resistance". Thanks for the link.

Comment: you actually answered your own question ... they are suitable because they are able to operate in cryogenic environments

Comment: @jsotola I asked *why are thin-film surface-mount resistors particularly suitable for use in cryogenic environments/conditions*, and you're saying that it's because "they are able to operate in cryogenic environments"; that's called circular reasoning.

Comment: are you asking  `why are thin-film surface-mount resistors able to operate in cryogenic environments?`, or are you asking something else?

Comment: @jsotola Yes. See the above comments regarding the "temperature coefficient of resistance".